# Telling mutable objects

Tags: ruby, immutability, mutable

Is there a method that tells if an object is mutable, similar to `mutable?` in the following? If not, what is the best way to implement it?

```
"abcde".mutable? # => true
0.mutable? # => false
```

---

To answer mu is too short and dbenhur's question, I do not like the syntax of `enumerated.inject(initial){...}` or `enumerated.each_with_object(initial){...}`. I wanted a method that reverses the receiver and the argument, and I wanted it to be available to a wide variety of classes; so that I have:

```
initial.my_new_method(enumerated){...}

0.my_new_method(1..10){|sum, i| sum + i} # => 55
"a".my_new_method(b: 3, c: 4){|s, (k, v)| s + k.to_s * v} # => "abbbcccc"
```

This will make the return a modified version of the receiver, and is conceptually more natural. And with `my_new_method`, I wanted it to be non destructive. When the receiver is mutable, I further wanted to define a destructive version

```
initial.my_new_method!(enumerated){...}

"a".my_new_method!(b: 3, c: 4){|s, (k, v)| s << k.to_s * v} # => "abbbcccc"
```

So to detect whether the receiver is mutable or not is necessary. It does not matter if it is frozen. If I use the destructive version of the method with a frozen object, it will simply raise an error. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: @muistooshort For designing a method that behaves differently depending on whether it is mutable or not.

Comment: @muistooshort I added to my answer why I want it.

Comment: Why is simply raising an error okay in one situation but not another? If someone wants to misuse this method then they're welcome to shoot their own foot as many times as they like.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I came up with this

```
class Object
  def mutable?; !!(dup rescue false) end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you whether something is mutable in any meaningful way. It just tells whether an object has a `dup` method that doesn't raise an error. A frozen object would respond true while a Singleton with lots of mutable state would return false.

Comment: +1 because only now I had the same idea. However 'immediate?' would be a better name.

Comment: @steenslag Right. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK all (unfrozen) objects are mutable, except nil, true, false and all integers and symbols.

Comment: The problem with this enumeration is it depends on a specific implementation of ruby.  The language definition doesn't say that these classes are immediate values, that's merely a detail of the current reference implementation.  Tomorrow ruby-core may decide that Float shall be implemented as immediates and they will not have broken any language contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.frozen?` on an object to see if that instance of an object is immutable:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = Array.new
 => [] 
1.9.3p194 :002 > a.frozen?
 => false 
1.9.3p194 :003 > a.freeze
 => [] 
1.9.3p194 :004 > a.frozen?
 => true
```

After calling `.freeze` no other changes will be allowed on that instance of an Object, a `RuntimeError` will be thrown if anyone attempts to change a frozen object.

**EDIT:**

As check mentions below in the comments `0.frozen?` will correctly return `false` because 0 is an instance of the `Fixnum` class.

Comment: Note that this will tell you that `0` is not frozen. That isn't a mistake — it's the correct answer.

Comment: @Chuck Thank you for that I will add it to the post.

Comment: Based on what you described in your post, `frozen?` is exactly what you want.

Comment: No it is not. Your code cannot distinguish an (unfrozen) array and a fixnum. My question clearly states that I expect different results.

Comment: @sawa: What is the difference you are trying to establish here? Fixnums technically can have their state mutated if they are not frozen. Your expectation that Fixnums are immutable is mistaken, so a correct answer to the question "How do you detect immutable objects?" *must* violate that expectation. If Fixnums are meant to be treated like frozen objects even when they aren't, then the logical solution would just be to add `|| a.is_a? Fixnum` after the actual check for frozenness.

Comment: @sawa Your post asks to determine if an object is mutable. You don't say anything about type at all. And of course what I posted does NOT differentiate between an unfrozen array and a fixnum, all it checks for is mutability, not type. It would be simple to add a type check like Chuck suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There are two properties that can make an object immutable in ruby

1) the object may be frozen with [`Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze), in which case your immutability check is [`Object#frozen?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-frozen-3F)

2) The object may be an [immediate value](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=ruby+immediate+vs+reference+objects&source=bl&ots=fIFgrabufz&sig=ew6vOJfvpNJrJD_Z4g15gEFeQIM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fql3UK7dIOWujALHqYDoAQ&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=ruby%20immediate%20vs%20reference%20objects&f=false). There's no built-in method I know of to tell that an object is immediate, so one must rely on a side-effect of the immediate nature.  Immediate values are not permitted to have singleton-classes defined on them, so I might try the following as a proxy:

```
class Object
  def immediate_value?
    class <<self; end
    return false
  rescue TypeError
    return true
  end

  def mutable?
    !(frozen? || immediate_value?)
  end
end
```

While this is probably a pretty reliable detector (I don't know of another mechanism that prevents opening the singleton class of an object), it does have the unfortunate side-effect of creating a singleton class for each object so queried.

Comment: I do not use the method `freeze`, so I do not need to consider the first case. The second part seems close to what I want, except for the downside of creating a class, as you mention. I didn't know about that restriction. It's good to know that.

Comment: @sawa if you're going to inject a method #mutable? into a builtin class (Object), you should absolutely consider frozen? part of the state check whether you use it today or not. "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live." It's probably a bad idea anyway and it's not at all clear why you want it.

Comment: I added to my answer why I want it.